# How to use paypal Subscribe with IPN and how to know if someone canceled

Tags: paypal

I am trying to create a subscription on a website where the user is charged every month. When they pay, a data column in my database changes from 0 to 1. If they cancel, that same column would change back to 0.

I have already created a buy button that does this, that once they buy, it changes the column to 1. What would I need to add to use the subscription button instead and if they cancel to change it back to 0?

Here is my code: would this create the subscription button? I modified my buy button with a subscription button I found on paypal.

```
  <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="cccc@msn.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="$info">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://ccccc.com/application.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.ccccc.com/index.php">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.ccccc.com/ipn.php">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$uid">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

HERE is my IPN code: would would i need to add to here to get it to work with subscription and if they cancel change it back to 0. Is there a variable that is sent when the user is canceled or would I need to create a new file that handles canceled accounts?

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","theelit9_chris","");
mysql_select_db("theelit9_date",$connection);



// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_POST["custom"]);

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

    if ($payment_status == 'Completed') {

        $txn_id_check = "SELECT `txn_id` FROM `log` WHERE `txn_id` = '".$txn_id."'";
        $result = mysql_query($txn_id_check);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) !=1 ) {

            if ($receiver_email=='xxxx@msn.com') {

                if ($payment_amount == '0.01' && $payment_currency == 'USD') {

                    $log_query = "INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('','".$txn_id."','".$payer_email."')";

                     $update_user_level = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_level` = '2', WHERE `id`='".$user_id."'";



            mysql_select_db("theelit9_date",$connection);
            $retval = mysql_query( $log_query, $connection );
            $retval1 = mysql_query( $update_user_level, $connection );
            if(! $retval && !$retval1)
                {
                die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                    }

                }

            }

        }

}

else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation
}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a buyer cancels their subscription, PayPal will send you an IPN with either `txn_type=subscr_cancel` or `txn_type=recurring_payment_profile_cancel` (depending on the exact type of subscription that was created).  You can then look at either the `subscr_id` or `recurring_payment_id` parameter to determine the subscription ID of the subscription that was just cancelled.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  So when someone cancels, would it still be saving the "<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$uid">"  when they originally sign up?  Would I be able to just add an else if(txn_type=subscr_cancel) to just set user_level back to 0?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes, any `custom` values that you pass in with your button should be passed back with all the IPN messages for that subscription.